# Help with iPhone sample code

Tags: iphone, cocoa, ios

I'm trying to build this iPhone sample:

http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

but I'm having trouble since I am new to both iPhone development and the Mac world.  From the **Build Preparation** section, I've downloaded the source code, but step 2 here is to "set [my] config_site.h" to a particular value.  Do I just double-click this file in Finder and change it there?  I can't actually find this file anywhere in the source.

The next section (**Building PJSIP**) says to "Just run:" this:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ ./configure-iphone
$ make dep && make clean && make
```

but I don't have any idea what it means to "just run" something on a Mac.  I also don't have any idea what path to use or how to get my downloaded source from Finder into a path location somewhere.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can just edit config_site.h from the finder, although you'll need to create it first.  You'll need to run the terminal app to do the rest, its in the Utilities folder of the Application directory.

Assuming your code path is: dev/ios/pjsip you would type:

```
cd dev/ios/pjsip
./configure-iphone
make dep && make clean && make
```

You'll then need to follow the rest of the instructions on building for the simulator etc...

Comment: thanks for the info. Unfortunately, I'm still at too rudimentary a stage to make any sense of these instructions. My downloaded code contains no `config_site.h` file, and I'm not sure where or how to create it. Right now, I only have the downloaded folder in my Downloads window - I don't know how to get it out of here and install it on my HD somewhere.

Comment: You create the config_site.h file in the include/pj folder.  It only has to contain those two lines from the instructions.  I suggest copying the whole folder somewhere else on your HD but you can do it from downloads if you like.  Your path would be Downloads/pjsip/

Comment: It's mostly working, but now I'm getting two weird little compile errors when I try to build the project in XCode. Thanks for getting me this far.

Comment: Got it all working finally, thanks (I fixed the compile errors by targeting the 4.0 SDK and 3.0 OS version - no clue why that worked). I greatly appreciate your assistance. FYI, I'm going to unselect your answer in a few days, offer a bounty and then reselect it. It's essentially the StackOverflow way of tipping. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're really new to development I would recommend doing everything through XCode projects rather than command line make files.

Comment: No argument there, but in this case I don't have any choice.